# Passing method with datetime parameter in eval for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a server side method as below which calculates the Age and takes in Date Of Birth and current date :

```
 protected int CalculateAge(DateTime DOB, DateTime now)
{
    int age = now.Year - DOB.Year;
    if (now.Month < DOB.Month || (now.Month == DOB.Month && now.Day < DOB.Day)) age--;
    return age;
}
```

Now i want to bind the age in a gridview label field as below :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAge" Text='<%# CalculateAge(Eval("DOB"),Eval(DateTime.Now)) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

but it says it has invalid arguments.

What are my options to use the CalculateAge method?

Edit: So, I decided to get rid of DateTime.Now and use DOB as the only input parameter like below :

```
protected int CalculateAge(DateTime DOB)
{
    int age = DateTime.Now.Year - DOB.Year;
    if (DateTime.Now.Month < DOB.Month || (DateTime.Now.Month == DOB.Month && DateTime.Now.Day < DOB.Day)) age--;
    return age;
}
```

and

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAge" Text='<%# CalculateAge(Bind("DOB")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and it still says invalid arguments for this method

Comment: Try `DateTime.Now` directly without `eval`

Comment: @Bharadwaj - Please chk my edited question

Comment: What if **DOB** isn't a date time object may be it's a string or It's null both can cause **invalid arguments** exception. Just for starter try converting it to date time e.g. `<%# CalculateAge(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DOB")),DateTime.Now) %>`

Comment: @Suprabhat - DOB comes in from my database table with column datatype datetime

Comment: Like I said try adding this and check if still you are getting same syntax error `Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DOB"))`

Comment: Thanks a ton,it worked.